# UDP Broadcasting with PHP

Tags: php, sockets, networking, udp, broadcast

I cannot figure how to broadcast a UDP datagram to my local network with PHP.
This is the sample code I use :

```
$socket = stream_socket_client("udp://255.255.255.255:12478", $errno, $errstr);
```

I tried with 192.168.0.255 instead of 255.255.255.255 but I get the same result :

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to udp://255.255.255.255:12478 (Permission denied)
```

Is this a limitation in the configuration of my OS (Debian Linux) ? Or a misuse of broadcasting options on my side ?

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks !

Lionel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms 'udp' and 'stream' are mutually exclusive. Also broadcasting is very different from other network operations.

See the note at the bottom of the [socket_sendto()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php) manual page. (The first hit if you google for 'php udp broadcast')